# Getting Access to fetch at 'https://graphql error in console when running the protractor script

Tags: javascript, docker, graphql, protractor

I running some scripts using protractor on the docker host and in my console I am getting the following error. in my script I have not used any graphQL or fetch but not sure why this error is thrown in console. The scripts are still fine and getting through, but all I concern is about that error or warning. Please let me know if you need to look in to my code for config file or anything else. so I can paste here

> [1103/185005.288:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to fetch at
> 'https://graphql-gateway-dev-raven.ocp-nonprod.xxx.xxx.xxx/graphql'
> from origin
> 'https://peregrine-webapp-dev-raven.ocp-nonprod.xxx.xxx.xxx' has been
> blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your
> needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with
> CORS disabled.", source:
> https://peregrine-webapp-dev-raven.ocp-nonprod.xxx.xxx.xxx/mailboxes
> (0)

> [1103/185005.292:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "[Network error]: TypeError:
> Failed to fetch", source:
> https://peregrine-webapp-dev-raven.ocp-nonprod.xxx.xxx.xxx/static/js/2.3f6abf4a.chunk.js
> (2)

Comment: Whether you made the call or a library you're using made it, it's getting rejected, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)